# Cannot make transaction paypal magento

Tags: magento2, php, paypal

I am trying to check out through paypal, I have put all the details in the paypal configuration in magento like username password etc.

The issue is when i login through paypal and then click continue when checking out i am getting following error, Here is sc shot.

https://prnt.sc/mkjvxd

Edit: I am using paypal sandbox account configuration

Comment: Have you made sure you are using the correct sandbox details?

Comment: Yes, I have used correct sandbox details.

Comment: I would recheck if you are using the token based validation i would reinput that also  see this if Encrypted Website Payments set to ON. if so try turning it off

Comment: From where i can set it to off?

Comment: If you go u to PayPal under your merchant settings it should have it under instant payment notification